# Pythagorean Triples Single Sum

Tags: number-theory

Let us suppose we have pythagoras triples $(a, b, c)$ such that
$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.

In this case primitive triples can be formed by $(m^2 - n^2, 2mn, m^2 + n^2)$ where $gcd(m,n) = 1$ and $m>n>0$.

For each primitive, we get a distinct sum value S, where S = a + b + c.

We can also see that Sum values can be constructed by using **2 distinct** primitive triples. Such as,

$5 \times (3,4,5) = (15, 20, 25)$ hence $S = 60$

or

$2\times ( 5,12,13) = (10, 24, 26)$ and $S= 60$

My question is that is there a way (equation or a pattern) such that we can find  S values, that can be constructed by using 2 distinct primitive triples, by using  (a,b,c) or m and n

Comment: To be clear: are you asking if all possible values of $S$ are associated with exactly $2$ triples, or if there is a method to find the triples or $S$ values with this property?

Comment: @Vedvart1 a method to find the triples of S with this property

Comment: Okay, just a bit more clarification: does it need to be *exactly* two distinct triples, or *at least* two distinct triples?

Comment: @Vedvart1 at least 2

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_1=a_1+b_1+c_1=2m_1^2+2m_1n_1$ and $S_2=a_2+b_2+c_2=2m_2^2+2m_2n_2$. You are asking if you can find $k_1$ and $k_2$ such that $k_1(2m_1^2+2m_1n_1)=k_2(2m_2^2+2m_2n_2)$. That should be readily accomplished by finding $\frac{k_1}{k_2}=\frac{m_2^2+m_2n_2}{m_1^2+m_1n_1}$ and (optionally) setting it in its lowest terms.